# Mootools get height use for dif. height

Tags: navigation, height, mootools

I looking for a solution i have a drop downnavi and there are 3 sub menüs (second level) i want that the whole BG ot the navi get the same height of the open navi.

Now i have that.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $$('.submenu a').addEvents({
        mouseenter: function(){
         $$('.navi').set('tween', {
            duration: 1000,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Bounce.easeOut
          }).tween('height', '145px');
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
           $$('.navi').set('tween', {}).tween('height', '60px');
        }
      });
```

I want that I can use the height of the open subnav as tweet height,

Like that.

```
.tween('height', HEIGHT FROM SUBNAV+60px);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite difficult to understand the question, so I answer it in two ways

1. In mootools more there is element.measure and with that you can measure a hidden element. `this` will be bound to the element you want to measure.

   var size = $('hiddenElement').measure(function(){
       return this.getSize();
   });

Please note that there is also `getDimensions` and `getComputedSize` in Mootools and they all differ in how they measure.

1. If you want to measure the height of elements above/below your submenu you can do that with a loop.

var height = 0;
$$('li').every(function(el){
    var size = el.getSize();
    height = height + size.y; // for instance

```
// return false to break 
return true;
```

})

With some more information about your HTML it would be easier to answer the question.